# Call to a member function addArguments() on null

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, phpunit, symfony-console

I try to mock my laravel console command for PHPUnit testing. As constructor argument it requires an instance of the laravel config repository:

```php
<?php 
class AmazingCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_something_to_be_working()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(AmazingCommand::class)
            ->setConstructorArgs([
                $this->app->make(Repository::class),
                $this->app->make(ConnectionInterface::class)
            ])
            ->getMock();
        // ... to be continued. Error appears already here
    }
}
```

The corresponding constructor of my console command looks like this: (where `Repository` is of type `Illuminate\Config\Repository`)

```php
    /**
     * @param Repository          $config
     * @param ConnectionInterface $db
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
     */
    public function __construct(Repository $config, ConnectionInterface $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->schemaManager = $db->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
        $this->schemaManager->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

        $this->config = $config;

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

So if I run my unit tests now I receive this error:

> 1) Tests\Unit\Commands\ AmazingCommandTest::test_something_to_be_working
>   Error: Call to a member function addArguments() on null
>
> /Users/xyz/Projects/packages/amazingpackage/foobar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:144

This points to a line within the method `protected function configureUsingFluentDefinition() {}`:

`$this->getDefinition()->addArguments($arguments);` where getDefinition() returns an InputDefinition:

```
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition {#3167
  -arguments: []
  -requiredCount: 0
  -hasAnArrayArgument: false
  -hasOptional: false
  -options: []
  -shortcuts: []
}
```

`getDefinition()` just checks if `$this->definition` is defined and throws a LogicException if not.

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is there something I probably miss?

Comment: For whatever reason `getDefinition()` is returning NULL. You need to find out why that is

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an integration (feature) test which calls the artisan command through `$this->artisan('command' [/*...args*/])` **instead** and *moved* the functionality to separate classes which can be tested with PHPUnit easier.

But I don't accept this as a valid answer because it's just a workaround. I think there may be a bug or I really miss something.